# How to add json data in ConfigMap creation in ArgoCD

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, argoproj

I'm trying to create a ConfigMap with ArgoCD.

I've created a `volumes.yaml` file as such

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: persistent-volumes-argo
  labels:
    grafana_dashboard: "1"
    project: "foo"
data:
  kubernetes.json: |
{{ .Files.Get "dashboards/persistent-volumes.json" | indent 4 }}
```

But ArgoCD doesn't seem to be able to read the data, the way a standard Helm deployment would.

I've tried adding the data directly into the ConfigMap as such

(Data omitted for brevity)

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: persistent-volumes-argo
  labels:
    grafana_dashboard: "1"
    project: "foo"
data:
  kubernetes.json: |
  {
  "annotations": {
    "list": [
      {
        "builtIn": 1,
        "datasource": "-- Grafana --",
        "enable": true,
        "hide": true,
        "iconColor": "rgba(0, 211, 255, 1)",
        "limit": 100,
        "name": "Annotations & Alerts",
        "showIn": 0,
        "type": "dashboard"
      }
    ]
  },
  "editable": true,
  "gnetId": 13646,
  "graphTooltip": 0,
  "iteration": 1659421503107,
  "links": [],
  "panels": [
    {
      "collapsed": false,
      "datasource": null,
      "fieldConfig": {
        "defaults": {},
        "overrides": []
      },
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 1,
        "w": 24,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
      },
      "id": 26,
      "panels": [],
      "title": "Alerts",
      "type": "row"
    },
    {
      "datasource": "$datasource",
      "fieldConfig": {
        "defaults": {
          "color": {
            "mode": "thresholds"
          },
          "mappings": [],
          "noValue": "--",
          "thresholds": {
            "mode": "absolute",
            "steps": [
              {
                "color": "semi-dark-red",
                "value": null
              },
              {
                "color": "light-green",
                "value": -0.0001
              },
              {
                "color": "semi-dark-red",
                "value": 0.0001
              }
            ]
          },
          "unit": "none"
        },
        "overrides": []
      },
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 4,
        "w": 8,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 1
      },
      "id": 21,
      "options": {
        "colorMode": "background",
        "graphMode": "area",
        "justifyMode": "auto",
        "orientation": "auto",
        "reduceOptions": {
          "calcs": [
            "mean"
          ],
          "fields": "",
          "values": false
        },
        "text": {},
        "textMode": "auto"
      },
      "pluginVersion": "8.0.3",
      "targets": [
        {
          "expr": "count (max by (persistentvolumeclaim,namespace) (kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes{namespace=~\"${k8s_namespace}\"} ) and (max by (persistentvolumeclaim,namespace) (kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes{namespace=~\"${k8s_namespace}\"} )) / (max by (persistentvolumeclaim,namespace) (kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes{namespace=~\"${k8s_namespace}\"} )) >= (${warning_threshold} / 100)) or vector (0)",
          "instant": true,
          "interval": "",
          "legendFormat": "",
          "refId": "A"
        }
      ],
      "timeFrom": null,
      "timeShift": null,
      "title": "PVCs Above Warning Threshold",
      "type": "stat"
    },
    {
      "datasource": "$datasource",
      "fieldConfig": {
        "defaults": {
          "color": {
            "mode": "thresholds"
          },
          "decimals": 0,
          "mappings": [],
          "noValue": "--",
          "thresholds": {
            "mode": "absolute",
            "steps": [
              {
                "color": "semi-dark-red",
                "value": null
              },
              {
                "color": "light-green",
                "value": -0.0001
              },
              {
                "color": "semi-dark-red",
                "value": 0.0001
              }
            ]
          },
          "unit": "none"
        },
        "overrides": []
      },
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 4,
        "w": 8,
        "x": 8,
        "y": 1
      },
      "id": 24,
      "options": {
        "colorMode": "background",
        "graphMode": "area",
        "justifyMode": "auto",
        "orientation": "auto",
        "reduceOptions": {
          "calcs": [
            "mean"
          ],
          "fields": "",
          "values": false
        },
        "text": {},
        "textMode": "auto"
      },
      "pluginVersion": "8.0.3",
      "targets": [
        {
          "expr": "count((kube_persistentvolumeclaim_status_phase{namespace=~\"${k8s_namespace}\",phase=\"Pending\"}==1)) or vector(0)",
          "instant": true,
          "interval": "",
          "legendFormat": "",
          "refId": "A"
        }
      ],
      "timeFrom": null,
      "timeShift": null,
      "title": "PVCs in Pending State",
      "transformations": [
        {
          "id": "organize",
          "options": {}
        }
      ],
      "type": "stat"
    },
    {
      "datasource": "$datasource",
      "fieldConfig": {
        "defaults": {
          "color": {
            "mode": "thresholds"
          },
          "decimals": 0,
          "mappings": [],
          "noValue": "--",
          "thresholds": {
            "mode": "absolute",
            "steps": [
              {
                "color": "semi-dark-red",
                "value": null
              },
              {
                "color": "light-green",
                "value": -0.0001
              },
              {
                "color": "semi-dark-red",
                "value": 0.0001
              }
            ]
          },
          "unit": "none"
        },
        "overrides": []
      },
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 4,
        "w": 8,
        "x": 16,
        "y": 1
      },
      "id": 23,
      "options": {
        "colorMode": "background",
        "graphMode": "area",
        "justifyMode": "auto",
        "orientation": "auto",
        "reduceOptions": {
          "calcs": [
            "mean"
          ],
          "fields": "",
          "values": false
        },
        "text": {},
        "textMode": "auto"
      },
      "pluginVersion": "8.0.3",
      "targets": [
        {
          "expr": "count((kube_persistentvolumeclaim_status_phase{namespace=~\"${k8s_namespace}\",phase=\"Lost\"}==1)) or vector(0)",
          "instant": true,
          "interval": "",
          "legendFormat": "",
          "refId": "A"
        }
      ],
      "timeFrom": null,
      "timeShift": null,
      "title": "PVCs in Lost State",
      "transformations": [
        {
          "id": "organize",
          "options": {}
        }
      ],
      "type": "stat"
    },
    {
      "collapsed": false,
      "datasource": null,
      "fieldConfig": {
        "defaults": {},
        "overrides": []
      },
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 1,
        "w": 24,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 5
      },
      "id": 17,
      "panels": [],
      "title": "Usage statistics",
      "type": "row"
    },
    {
      "datasource": "$datasource",
      "fieldConfig": {
        "defaults": {
          "color": {
            "mode": "thresholds"
          },
          "custom": {
            "align": null,
            "displayMode": "auto",
            "filterable": false
          },
          "mappings": [],
          "noValue": "--",
          "thresholds": {
            "mode": "absolute",
            "steps": [
              {
                "color": "light-green",
                "value": null
              }
            ]
          },
          "unit": "none"
        },
        "overrides": [
          {
            "matcher": {
              "id": "byName",
              "options": "Used (%)"
            },
            "properties": [
              {
                "id": "custom.displayMode",
                "value": "gradient-gauge"
              },
              {
                "id": "thresholds",
                "value": {
                  "mode": "absolute",
                  "steps": [
                    {
                      "color": "light-green",
                      "value": null
                    },
                    {
                      "color": "semi-dark-yellow",
                      "value": 70
                    },
                    {
                      "color": "dark-red",
                      "value": 80
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "id": "decimals",
                "value": 1
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "matcher": {
              "id": "byName",
              "options": "Status"
            },
            "properties": [
              {
                "id": "custom.displayMode",
                "value": "color-background"
              },
              {
                "id": "mappings",
                "value": [
                  {
                    "options": {
                      "0": {
                        "text": "Bound"
                      },
                      "1": {
                        "text": "Pending"
                      },
                      "2": {
                        "text": "Lost"
                      }
                    },
                    "type": "value"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "thresholds",
                "value": {
                  "mode": "absolute",
                  "steps": [
                    {
                      "color": "light-green",
                      "value": null
                    },
                    {
                      "color": "light-green",
                      "value": 0
                    },
                    {
                      "color": "semi-dark-orange",
                      "value": 1
                    },
                    {
                      "color": "semi-dark-red",
                      "value": 2
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "id": "noValue",
                "value": "--"
              },
              {
                "id": "custom.align",
                "value": "center"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "matcher": {
              "id": "byName",
              "options": "Namespace"
            },
            "properties": [
              {
                "id": "custom.width",
                "value": 120
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "matcher": {
              "id": "byName",
              "options": "Status"
            },
            "properties": [
              {
                "id": "custom.width",
                "value": 80
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "matcher": {
              "id": "byName",
              "options": "Capacity (GiB)"
            },
            "properties": [
              {
                "id": "custom.width",
                "value": 120
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "matcher": {
              "id": "byName",
              "options": "Used (GiB)"
            },
            "properties": [
              {
                "id": "custom.width",
                "value": 120
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "matcher": {
              "id": "byName",
              "options": "Available (GiB)"
            },
            "properties": [
              {
                "id": "custom.width",
                "value": 120
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "matcher": {
              "id": "byName",
              "options": "StorageClass"
            },
            "properties": [
              {
                "id": "custom.width",
                "value": 150
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "matcher": {
              "id": "byName",
              "options": "PersistentVolumeClaim"
            },
            "properties": [
              {
                "id": "custom.width",
                "value": 370
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 12,
        "w": 24,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 6
      },
      "id": 29,
      "interval": "",
      "options": {
        "frameIndex": 2,
        "showHeader": true,
        "sortBy": [
          {
            "desc": false,
            "displayName": "PersistentVolumeClaim"
          }
        ]
      },
      "pluginVersion": "8.0.3",
      "targets": [
        {
          "expr": " sum by (persistentvolumeclaim,namespace,storageclass,volumename) (kube_persistentvolumeclaim_info{namespace=~\"${k8s_namespace}\"})",
          "format": "table",
          "instant": true,
          "interval": "",
          "legendFormat": "",
          "refId": "A"
        },
        {
          "expr": "sum by (persistentvolumeclaim) (kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes{namespace=~\"${k8s_namespace}\"}/1024/1024/1024)",
          "format": "table",
          "instant": true,
          "interval": "",
          "legendFormat": "",
          "refId": "B"
        },
        {
          "expr": "sum by (persistentvolumeclaim) (kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes{namespace=~\"${k8s_namespace}\"}/1024/1024/1024)",
          "format": "table",
          "instant": true,
          "interval": "",
          "legendFormat": "",
          "refId": "C"
        },
        {
          "expr": "sum by (persistentvolumeclaim) (kubelet_volume_stats_available_bytes{namespace=~\"${k8s_namespace}\"}/1024/1024/1024)",
          "format": "table",
          "instant": true,
          "interval": "",
          "legendFormat": "",
          "refId": "D"
        },
        {
          "expr": "sum(kube_persistentvolumeclaim_status_phase{namespace=~\"${k8s_namespace}\",phase=~\"(Pending|Lost)\"}) by (persistentvolumeclaim) + sum(kube_persistentvolumeclaim_status_phase{namespace=~\"${k8s_namespace}\",phase=~\"(Lost)\"}) by (persistentvolumeclaim)",
          "format": "table",
          "instant": true,
          "interval": "",
          "legendFormat": "",
          "refId": "E"
        },
        {
          "expr": "sum by (persistentvolumeclaim) (kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes{namespace=~\"${k8s_namespace}\"}/kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes{namespace=~\"${k8s_namespace}\"} * 100)",
          "format": "table",
          "instant": true,
          "interval": "",
          "legendFormat": "",
          "refId": "F"
        }
      ],
      "timeFrom": null,
      "timeShift": null,
      "title": "Persistent Volume Claim",
      "transformations": [
        {
          "id": "seriesToColumns",
          "options": {
            "byField": "persistentvolumeclaim"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "organize",
          "options": {
            "excludeByName": {
              "Time": true,
              "Time 1": true,
              "Time 2": true,
              "Time 3": true,
              "Time 4": true,
              "Time 5": true,
              "Time 6": true,
              "Value #A": true
            },
            "indexByName": {},
            "renameByName": {
              "Time 1": "",
              "Time 2": "",
              "Time 3": "",
              "Time 4": "",
              "Time 5": "",
              "Time 6": "",
              "Value #A": "",
              "Value #B": "Capacity (GiB)",
              "Value #C": "Used (GiB)",
              "Value #D": "Available (GiB)",
              "Value #E": "Status",
              "Value #F": "Used (%)",
              "namespace": "Namespace",
              "persistentvolumeclaim": "PersistentVolumeClaim",
              "storageclass": "StorageClass",
              "volumename": "PhysicalVolume"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "type": "table"
    },
    {
      "datasource": "$datasource",
      "fieldConfig": {
        "defaults": {
          "custom": {
            "align": null,
            "displayMode": "auto",
            "filterable": false
          },
          "mappings": [],
          "thresholds": {
            "mode": "absolute",
            "steps": [
              {
                "color": "green",
                "value": null
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "overrides": []
      },
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 5,
        "w": 24,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 18
      },
      "id": 7,
      "options": {
        "showHeader": true,
        "sortBy": [
          {
            "desc": true,
            "displayName": "Status"
          }
        ]
      },
      "pluginVersion": "8.0.3",
      "targets": [
        {
          "expr": "kube_storageclass_info",
          "format": "table",
          "interval": "",
          "legendFormat": "",
          "refId": "A"
        }
      ],
      "timeFrom": null,
      "timeShift": null,
      "title": "Storage Class",
      "transformations": [
        {
          "id": "organize",
          "options": {
            "excludeByName": {
              "Time": true,
              "Value": true,
              "__name__": true,
              "app_kubernetes_io_instance": true,
              "app_kubernetes_io_name": true,
              "instance": true,
              "job": true,
              "kubernetes_namespace": true,
              "kubernetes_pod_name": true,
              "pod_template_hash": true
            },
            "indexByName": {
              "Time": 1,
              "Value": 13,
              "__name__": 2,
              "app_kubernetes_io_instance": 3,
              "app_kubernetes_io_name": 4,
              "instance": 5,
              "job": 6,
              "kubernetes_namespace": 7,
              "kubernetes_pod_name": 8,
              "pod_template_hash": 9,
              "provisioner": 10,
              "reclaimPolicy": 11,
              "storageclass": 0,
              "volumeBindingMode": 12
            },
            "renameByName": {
              "provisioner": "Provisioner",
              "reclaimPolicy": "ReclaimPolicy",
              "storageclass": "StorageClass",
              "volumeBindingMode": "VolumeBindingMode"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "groupBy",
          "options": {
            "fields": {
              "Provisioner": {
                "aggregations": [],
                "operation": "groupby"
              },
              "ReclaimPolicy": {
                "aggregations": [],
                "operation": "groupby"
              },
              "StorageClass": {
                "aggregations": [],
                "operation": "groupby"
              },
              "VolumeBindingMode": {
                "aggregations": [],
                "operation": "groupby"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "type": "table"
    },
    {
      "collapsed": false,
      "datasource": null,
      "fieldConfig": {
        "defaults": {},
        "overrides": []
      },
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 1,
        "w": 24,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 23
      },
      "id": 15,
      "panels": [],
      "title": "Graphical usage data ",
      "type": "row"
    },
    {
      "aliasColors": {},
      "bars": false,
      "dashLength": 10,
      "dashes": false,
      "datasource": "$datasource",
      "fill": 0,
      "fillGradient": 0,
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 12,
        "w": 24,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 24
      },
      "hiddenSeries": false,
      "id": 9,
      "legend": {
        "alignAsTable": true,
        "avg": true,
        "current": true,
        "max": true,
        "min": true,
        "rightSide": true,
        "show": true,
        "total": false,
        "values": true
      },
      "lines": true,
      "linewidth": 1,
      "nullPointMode": "null",
      "options": {
        "alertThreshold": true
      },
      "percentage": false,
      "pluginVersion": "8.0.3",
      "pointradius": 2,
      "points": false,
      "renderer": "flot",
      "seriesOverrides": [],
      "spaceLength": 10,
      "stack": false,
      "steppedLine": false,
      "targets": [
        {
          "expr": "(max by (persistentvolumeclaim,namespace) (kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes{namespace=~\"${k8s_namespace}\"}))",
          "interval": "",
          "legendFormat": "{{namespace}} ({{persistentvolumeclaim}})",
          "refId": "A"
        }
      ],
      "thresholds": [],
      "timeFrom": null,
      "timeRegions": [],
      "timeShift": null,
      "title": "All Running PVCs Used Bytes",
      "tooltip": {
        "shared": true,
        "sort": 2,
        "value_type": "individual"
      },
      "type": "graph",
      "xaxis": {
        "buckets": null,
        "mode": "time",
        "name": null,
        "show": true,
        "values": []
      },
      "yaxes": [
        {
          "format": "bytes",
          "label": null,
          "logBase": 1,
          "max": null,
          "min": null,
          "show": true
        },
        {
          "format": "Date & time",
          "label": null,
          "logBase": 1,
          "max": null,
          "min": null,
          "show": true
        }
      ],
      "yaxis": {
        "align": false,
        "alignLevel": null
      }
    },
    {
      "collapsed": true,
      "datasource": null,
      "fieldConfig": {
        "defaults": {},
        "overrides": []
      },
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 1,
        "w": 24,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 36
      },
      "id": 19,
      "panels": [
        {
          "aliasColors": {},
          "bars": false,
          "dashLength": 10,
          "dashes": false,
          "datasource": "$datasource",
          "fieldConfig": {
            "defaults": {
              "custom": {}
            },
            "overrides": []
          },
          "fill": 0,
          "fillGradient": 0,
          "gridPos": {
            "h": 7,
            "w": 24,
            "x": 0,
            "y": 41
          },
          "hiddenSeries": false,
          "id": 11,
          "legend": {
            "alignAsTable": true,
            "avg": true,
            "current": false,
            "max": false,
            "min": false,
            "rightSide": true,
            "show": true,
            "total": false,
            "values": true
          },
          "lines": true,
          "linewidth": 1,
          "nullPointMode": "null",
          "options": {
            "alertThreshold": true
          },
          "percentage": false,
          "pluginVersion": "7.2.1",
          "pointradius": 2,
          "points": false,
          "renderer": "flot",
          "seriesOverrides": [],
          "spaceLength": 10,
          "stack": false,
          "steppedLine": false,
          "targets": [
            {
              "expr": "rate(kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes{namespace=~\"${k8s_namespace}\"}[1h])",
              "instant": false,
              "interval": "",
              "legendFormat": "{{namespace}} ({{persistentvolumeclaim}})",
              "refId": "A"
            }
          ],
          "thresholds": [],
          "timeFrom": null,
          "timeRegions": [],
          "timeShift": null,
          "title": "Hourly Volume Usage Rate",
          "tooltip": {
            "shared": true,
            "sort": 2,
            "value_type": "individual"
          },
          "type": "graph",
          "xaxis": {
            "buckets": null,
            "mode": "time",
            "name": null,
            "show": true,
            "values": []
          },
          "yaxes": [
            {
              "format": "binBps",
              "label": null,
              "logBase": 1,
              "max": null,
              "min": null,
              "show": true
            },
            {
              "format": "Date & time",
              "label": null,
              "logBase": 1,
              "max": null,
              "min": null,
              "show": true
            }
          ],
          "yaxis": {
            "align": false,
            "alignLevel": null
          }
        },
        {
          "aliasColors": {},
          "bars": false,
          "dashLength": 10,
          "dashes": false,
          "datasource": "$datasource",
          "fieldConfig": {
            "defaults": {
              "custom": {}
            },
            "overrides": []
          },
          "fill": 0,
          "fillGradient": 0,
          "gridPos": {
            "h": 7,
            "w": 24,
            "x": 0,
            "y": 48
          },
          "hiddenSeries": false,
          "id": 12,
          "legend": {
            "alignAsTable": true,
            "avg": true,
            "current": false,
            "max": false,
            "min": false,
            "rightSide": true,
            "show": true,
            "total": false,
            "values": true
          },
          "lines": true,
          "linewidth": 1,
          "nullPointMode": "null",
          "options": {
            "alertThreshold": true
          },
          "percentage": false,
          "pluginVersion": "7.2.1",
          "pointradius": 2,
          "points": false,
          "renderer": "flot",
          "seriesOverrides": [],
          "spaceLength": 10,
          "stack": false,
          "steppedLine": false,
          "targets": [
            {
              "expr": "rate(kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes{namespace=~\"${k8s_namespace}\"}[1d])",
              "interval": "",
              "legendFormat": "{{namespace}} ({{persistentvolumeclaim}})",
              "refId": "A"
            }
          ],
          "thresholds": [],
          "timeFrom": null,
          "timeRegions": [],
          "timeShift": null,
          "title": "Daily Volume Usage Rate",
          "tooltip": {
            "shared": true,
            "sort": 2,
            "value_type": "individual"
          },
          "type": "graph",
          "xaxis": {
            "buckets": null,
            "mode": "time",
            "name": null,
            "show": true,
            "values": []
          },
          "yaxes": [
            {
              "format": "binBps",
              "label": null,
              "logBase": 1,
              "max": null,
              "min": null,
              "show": true
            },
            {
              "format": "Date & time",
              "label": null,
              "logBase": 1,
              "max": null,
              "min": null,
              "show": true
            }
          ],
          "yaxis": {
            "align": false,
            "alignLevel": null
          }
        },
        {
          "aliasColors": {},
          "bars": false,
          "dashLength": 10,
          "dashes": false,
          "datasource": "$datasource",
          "fieldConfig": {
            "defaults": {
              "custom": {}
            },
            "overrides": []
          },
          "fill": 0,
          "fillGradient": 0,
          "gridPos": {
            "h": 7,
            "w": 24,
            "x": 0,
            "y": 55
          },
          "hiddenSeries": false,
          "id": 13,
          "legend": {
            "alignAsTable": true,
            "avg": true,
            "current": false,
            "max": false,
            "min": false,
            "rightSide": true,
            "show": true,
            "total": false,
            "values": true
          },
          "lines": true,
          "linewidth": 1,
          "nullPointMode": "null",
          "options": {
            "alertThreshold": true
          }
        }
```

But this errors with `rpc error: code = FailedPrecondition desc = Failed to unmarshal "volumes.yaml": <nil>`

Is there a way to pass in json data when creating a ConfigMap with ArgoCD, either as a template or by dumping the data in the file?

Comment: convert the JSON to YAML, and put it in the value file, as argocd will keep sync with value file not sure if it can read from file so the value should work. and then data in configmap should be like data:   kubernetes.json: | {{ toJson .Values.configmap.json | indent 4 }}

Comment: Thanks @Adiii. Do you mean `{{ toJson .Values.configmap.yaml | indent 4 }}` or `{{ toJson .Values.configmap.json | indent 4 }}`?

I've done a JSON to YAML conversion and placed the YAML in a values file, but I still get the same error.

Comment: no, its actully the value object name, for example `configmap:
  json:
    id: 12
    realm: 123`

Comment: let me add as an answer as it hard to add in the comment,

Comment: btw are you using helm?

Comment: I'm not using Helm to deploy the configMap at the moment. 
I'm literally just creating a standalone configmap resource. But if using helm makes it easier, I'm happy to go this route

Comment: argocd speak well when it come helm and you will be happy to move to helm with argocd, no special magic you just need to specify the helm-chart app name https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/helm/

Comment: Thanks.. If you're able to add it as an answer, it would be super helpful and much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create configmap with argocd and helm

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "helm-chart.fullname" . }}-configmap
data:
  config.json : |
  {{ toJson .Values.configmap | indent 4 }}
```

and the value file should be like this, which is our JSON but converted to YAML

```
configmap:
  json:
    - rigid
    - better for data interchange
  yaml: 
    - slim and flexible
    - better for configuration
  object:
    key: value
    array:
      - null_value:
      - boolean: true
      - integer: 1
      - alias: &example aliases are like variables
      - alias: *example
  paragraph: >
    Blank lines denote

    paragraph breaks
  content: |-
    Or we
    can auto
    convert line breaks
    to save space
  alias: &foo
    bar: baz
  alias_reuse: *foo
```

[json2yaml](https://www.json2yaml.com/)

A complete demo app can be found [here](https://github.com/Adiii717/argocd-demo-app)

A very quick way to create app with the above configmap and demo app

```
argocd app create demo-app --repo https://github.com/Adiii717/argocd-demo-app.git --path helm-chart --dest-namespace default --dest-server https://kubernetes.default.svc --helm-set replicaCount=2
```

[image]
Make sure you also set

```
export ARGOCD_AUTH_TOKEN="tokeh
export ARGOCD_OPTS="--grpc-web"
export ARGOCD_SERVER="argocd.example.com"
```

added section for the [configmap](https://github.com/Adiii717/argocd-demo-app#configmap-creation)